# In this program(Java) I'm trying to make a dice roller. How do I make it so it rolls a bunch of times and adds the rolls?

Tags: java, return, while-loop

```
import java.util.Random;

public class dice
{
  private int times;
  private int roll;
  private int side;
  Random roller = new Random();



  public void setTimes(int sides)
  {
    times = sides;
  }

  public void setSides(int die)
  {
    side = die;
  }

  public int getRoll() //this is where the "rolling" happens
  { 
    int total = 0;
    int c = 0;
    while (c <= times)
    {
      c = c + 1;
      int rol = 0;
      roll = roller.nextInt(side) + 1;
      rol = rol + roll;
      total = rol;
    }
    return total;
  }
}
```

If you need the GUIWindow and the main, just ask

Comment: You should probably provide a simple main method that shows how you're calling `getRoll()`.

Comment: Is this homework?  What have you tried?  Why do you suspect it doesn't work?  If you ask questions of the form "please do my debugging for me" you are unlikely to get good advice, since it's a bit presumptuous.

Comment: Hey, you should select an answer if one of these helped you.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, rather than completely solving it for you and giving you the code... you've got a `total` variable, which would suggest it's the total of several values. But you're only ever *directly assigning* a value to it. Have you considered adding the current roll to `total`?

Comment: Fantastic! My gratitude towards thee is quite great!

Answer (score 2):

One problem that I see in your `getRoll()` method is that you're reinitializing the `rol` variable to zero every time through the loop.  Then you get a random value and add it to `rol`, assign the `total` to `rol`, then you return the `total`.  This will always result in `total` having the last random value you created.

You can get rid of the `rol` variable completely and just add the new `roll` to `total` each time through the loop.